# How can a crystal habit be round?

Tags: mineralogy, crystallography

I am confused how hematite can have a "botryoidal" habit when its crystal structure is trigonal, which is an angled structure.

How can an angled crystal present itself as rounded?

If a botryoidal crystal of hematite is examined microscopically, is it clear that it is trigonal? How is that?

Answer (score 4):

Botryoidal habit describes the arrangement of a large group of hematite crystals.

While hematite's trigonal crystal system describes the geometry of a single unit crystal of hematite,  the two terms are really not related at all. Many minerals with different crystal systems can have a botryoidal habit.

The difference between a Botryoidal habit and mineral's unit crystal geometry is a difference in scale. A botryoidal habit can be measured in inches to feet while crystal geometry is measured in Ångstroms.